# read 05_16_2012 from BALASB_1234_05_16_2012:14:31:37.tar file name

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to read `05_16_2012` from `BALASB_1234_05_16_2012:14:31:37.tar` file name using shell script. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO Balu! You'll get a much better response if you show us what you've tried and ask for help getting it working. For your particular question check out `awk` as one of many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo "EXTLOG_1234_05_16_2012:14:31:37.tar"|\
awk -F"_" '{sub(/:.*$/, "", $5); printf("%s_%s_%s\n", $3, $4, $5)}'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `both`? This is a single command (and fully tested)  entered in 2 lines with `\ ` for continuation. Use it like this: `echo "EXTLOG_1234_05_16_2012:14:31:37.tar"|awk -F"_" '{sub(/:.*$/, "", $5); printf("%s_%s_%s\n", $3, $4, $5)}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
date=$(echo *.tar | grep -Po '\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "BALASB_1234_05_16_2012:14:31:37.tar"|awk '{FS=OFS='_'}{print $3,$4,$5}'
```